# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Up-To-Date check always report up-to-date

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using VS2017 write C++ projects. After some version update, it cannot auto detect source file changes. The **Build**(F7) command always report something like:

```
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: hello, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Time Elapsed 3 ms
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Although I can use **Rebuild** to get things work, it could be quite slow for some large projects. Are there any idea about this problem, or about how the build process check whether sources are out-dated?

Thanks.

Comment: How was the solution built? Where is it stored? What files are there in the solution? Auto-generated?

Comment: This usually happens when the changes file is not in the project. Or the file is opened in another editor, and VS cannot save it.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Both solution build and project build produce the same message. I suspect it is the problem of Up-To-Date check. I tried to re-install VS2017, but it still cannot help. I tried common file locations including default VS project directory. The process is quite simple: create a new empty c++ project -> add a new source file -> write a simple main function. Things just cannot work. I don't want to re-install my Windows:(

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Thanks, I confirm that VS editor can save the file correctly. It just cannot be aware that files have been changed and project need to update.

Comment: Is this file in the project?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Of course it is. In fact I found such problem when I build large project with CMake. And then, I found even without CMake and use the most common routine to create a C++ project, it still cannot work. So I think there might be something wrong with the Up-To-Date check process. I have both VS2015 and 2017 on my system, previously both one works well. Now VS2015 still works but 2017 doesn't. I also have several PCs with VS2017, none of them have the same problem - all the others work well, but unfortunately, this broken one is my major workstation....It is quite strange.

Comment: Odd... Did you try reinstalling VS2017?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, I tried it several times. It is OK to use VS2015 instead, or do a clean system reinstall, but I just want to figure out how it happens. Thanks!

Comment: How is the dependency of the project on this file written in your cmake file?